# "Composed of" Vs. "Consists of"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, vocabulary, word-difference

I feel like there is no difference between the two words. Would you tell me what is the difference between them?

I'm an electrical engineer. Which one should I use to speak about electricity, electrons, wires, electromagnetic waves and so on...?

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no difference in meaning between 'consist of' and 'be composed of'.
Both are used to describe what something is formed or made of.

The difference is between their usage.  The former is used in the active voice, whereas the latter is in the passive voice.

Besides, the use of the latter is more formal.  The former can be used both in spoken and written formal English.

Comment: I completely agree that they're interchangeable.  I just wanted to add a side note about how I personally choose which to use.  Since compose is a also a verb meaning "to build" or "to create", I think that sometimes "composed of" is used a little more often when identifying the elements of something that's been constructed (The building is composed of bricks), while "consists of" would be used for something natural or abstract (The group of friends consists of four boys and two girls).  Again, maybe just a personal preference and definitely still interchangeable at the end of the day.

Comment: When I read "composed of" I infer that there's a "composition", and "consist of" gives me "consistence" in the same fashion. But that's a nuance remark.

Comment: Dr DrfbagIII,  I appreciate your comments, but there are many sentences in dictionaries using be composed of and consist of without making a distinction between these phrases.

Comment: What @Dr DrfbagIII said. Personally, in contexts where I feel the constituent parts have to be "gathered together" to form something, I'm probably more likely to go for ***comprising***. Dunno if that naturally follows somehow from the fact that etymologically, *comprise* started life with the now-obsolete sense *To lay hold on, take, catch, **seize***.

Comment: @Dr.D - I agree with your usage note, too. And if neither one sounds right, I might use _made from_, as in: _This cake batter is made from flour, milk, sugar, and eggs._ (Somehow, neither _composed of_ nor _comprised from_ seems like the right word there. It's tough to explain.)

Comment: How about this case: *Greese generally **consists of** a soap emulsified with mineral or vegetable oil*? Can I substitute with **is composed of** and there is no problem? I would be so thankful if you guys would reply to this comment.